# Changing file permissions on an HFS+ filesystem

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, readonly, hfs+

I ran the command `fdisk -l` to find out what my external drive is formatted to, I found out it's uses GPT partitions and the filesystem is HFS+.

When I try and create a new folder on the external drive I receive the following message:

```
chmod: changing permissions of 'file_name/': Read-only file system
```

If I run `mount` this is the output:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=dev)
/dev/sdc2 on /media/dev/andre backup type hfsplus (ro,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sde2 on /media/dev/andre_clients type hfsplus (ro,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
```

So now I ran `umount /dev/sde2` and unplugged the device then reconnected the device and ran the command `dmesg | tail` and got this information back:

```
[429154.613747] sd 14:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through
[429154.615995] sd 14:0:0:0: [sde] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[429154.616993] sd 14:0:0:0: [sde] Asking for cache data failed
[429154.616997] sd 14:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through
[429154.669277]  sde: sde1 sde2
[429154.671369] sd 14:0:0:0: [sde] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[429154.672742] sd 14:0:0:0: [sde] Asking for cache data failed
[429154.672747] sd 14:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through
[429154.672751] sd 14:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
[429157.047244] hfsplus: write access to a journaled filesystem is not supported, use the force option at your own risk, mounting read-only.
```

Would it now be safe to run `sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sde2 /media/dev/andre_clients` without loosing any infomation?

Comment: Can you give us the output of `mount` ? Might be that your system is mounted read only, so you should mount it read+write.

Comment: that's the output of command `mount`?

Can you please edit your question and put the output there?

Comment: One last thing: Please tell us, which device you are referring to. e.g. `/dev/sdX` or `/media/dev/X` etc.

Comment: This is the file I'm trying to change permissions on `/dev/sde2 on /media/dev/andre_clients`

Comment: The fact that the disk uses GPT partitions is irrelevant. What matters is the filesystem type, which is HFS+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Note:

It seems you need to mount a hfsplus as write/read, which is a bit problematic, because of it's journal function.

However, you can mount it as write/read as seen [here](http://raamdev.com/2008/mounting-hfs-with-write-access-in-debian/) and [here](https://superuser.com/a/365270/333431).

---

The problem is that `/dev/sde2` is mounted read only, according to the `ro` flag in the parentheses in the last line:

> /dev/sde2 on /media/dev/andre_clients type hfsplus (***ro***,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)

Therefore you can't change anything on this disk.

Remount it as read+write `rw`:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point
```

In your case:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sde2 /media/dev/andre_clients
```

Before you do that, though, make sure you mount the right partition identifier by using `dmesg | tail`, e.g.:

```
[25341.272519] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     [...]
[25341.273201] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[25341.284054] sd 2:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI removable disk
              [...]
[25343.681773]  sde: sde2
```

The most recent `sdX: sdXX` line gives you a hint on which partition identifier (the `sdXX` one) your device connection is identified with.

You can also check which dev your device is connected to, by doing

```
ll /dev/disk/by-id/
```

[This](https://superuser.com/a/361892/333431) will give you all symbolic links of the device and it's partitions:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Jul 22 16:02 usb-manufacturername_*serialnumber* -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jul 22 16:02 usb-manufacturername_*serialnumber*-part1 -> ../../sdb1
```

---

Comment: Will this affect any information on the disk

Comment: Only the information you change. e.g. creating a directory/file.

Comment: iv updated my question to after i run `dmesg | tail` also when i say affect i mean will i loose any information stored in `/dev/sde2 /media/dev/andre_clients`

Comment: Because I have alot of files inside that folder `andre_clients`

Comment: Well those folders are written onto your external drive aren't they? So if you safely unmount the disk (`umount /dev/sde2`) you shouldn't experience any loss as far as I know. Make a backup if you don't believe me :D! Also before doing `dmesg | tail`, unplug your external drive and plug it in, then do the command. But then, again, make sure you `umount` it safely before unplugging it.

Comment: so let me get this right, first run `umount /dev/sde2` to unmount the drive, then plug it back in and run `dmesg | tail` then run `sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sde2 /media/dev/andre_clients` is this correct??

Comment: Yes totally correct :)! Except look up in `dmesg | tail` if your device is really connected to `/dev/sde2`. It might be also possible, that the `mount -o remount...` command safely unmounts your disk and you only have to run this one command, but I am not sure about that. The above way is the safest one :)!

Comment: Cool let the games begin:D, PS, if I loose any files I'm going to be in big trouble, and I cant even make a back up because it wont let me even read the files.

Comment: Oh god I hope :D. But weird that you can't even read the files. It's is readable according to `ro`...

Comment: Ok looks like hfsplus has some problems being mounted with write. Can you execute the first and third command of this answer http://superuser.com/a/365270/333431 ? Do it after `umount` + `dmesg|tail`.

Comment: Thanks a million that last post just put the cherry on top you the bomb shot alot:D!!!!!

Comment: Hehe nice to know it worked :))!! Good teamwork!

Answer (score -1):

You need to turn off the journaling if you want to write to it from Ubuntu. Ubuntu only has support for writing to non-journaled HFS+ volumes. Disabling journaling from HFS+ is still possible up to OS X Yosemite 10.10

On your Mac:

- Open Disk Utility under Applications -> Utilities
- Select the volume to disable journaling on.
- Choose Disable Journaling from the File menu. (On later Mac OS versions you'll have to hold down the option button when you click the File menu. Or if you like Apple+J)

Now plug in the HFS+ Hard drive into Ubuntu and run this command:

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
```

Example output:

```
sda                       
├─sda1 vfat     300M     EFI

└─sda2 hfsplus  100G     VolumeName
```

So we are only interested in sda2 in that example.

```
sudo apt-get install hfsprogs
```

Create a folder in your home directory called backup and copy the full path of backup to put at the end of the following command:

```
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sda2 /home/user/backup
```

Now for good luck:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /home/user/backup
sudo chmod 775 /home/user/backup
```

Testing with terminal:

```
cd /home/user/backup
mkdir test
```

Now check with your file manager if test directory was created. May need to run the file manager as root when writing, e.g.:

```
sudo thunar
```